# Get most popular value from column with multiple values in each row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have currently ran into an issue with something I'm working on. The problem is that I want to get the most popular value from the TYPE column but each row in that column has multiple values with a **::** separator.

It could look something like this.

```
     -------------           --------------------------
     ||  TYPE   ||           ||    Another Column    ||     
     -------------           --------------------------
Value1::Value2::Value3  |             SomeValue
Value1::Value3          |             SomeValue
Value1                  |             SomeValue
Value45::Value1         |             SomeValue
Value3                  |             SomeValue
```

Prior to me merging the rows I could use the following query to get the most popular value in the TYPE column. But that would just give me something like `Value1::Value2::Value3` instead of `Value1` when doing it now.

```
SELECT TYPE, COUNT(TYPE) AS popularity FROM mytable GROUP BY TYPE ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 1
```

**To the question. Is there any query that I could use to get the most popular value even though there are multiple values in each row?**

Kind Regards,
Jonathan.

Comment: Wow.  It would be a pretty easy query **after you fix your data format**.  you should not be storing multiple values in a single column.  That is not the SQL way to store data.  Learn about junction/association tables.

Comment: When Chapter 2 of Bill Karwin's book "SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming" dis-recommends storing comma separated lists of values, the meaning was not to replace the comma separators with double colon separators.  https://www.slideshare.net/ara6225/sql-antipatterns-16612325  (To answer the question: "Yes. Given a finite maximum number of elements in the list of values,yes, it would be possible to construct a query that would achieve the result. But it wouldn't be pretty."

Comment: @GordonLinoff The problem is that if I were to split them up into different rows. Then I would have 3 almost similar rows instead of 1 row having 3 separated values.

Comment: @JonathanV The values of this column should be in a separate table with a foreign key pointing to this table, so you don't have to duplicate all the other columns.